# If/Then in Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need some help constructing an If/Then query in Access.  I want the New Comments field to populate based on the Cardholder, Approver, and Reconciler columns:

```
If only Cardholder is filled: New Comments field = A
If only Reconciler is filled: New Comments field = B
If only Approver is filled: New Comments field = C
If Cardholder & Reconciler filled:  New Comments field =D
If Cardholder & Approver filled: New Comments field = E
If Cardholder & Reconciler & Approver filled: New Comments field = F
If Reconciler & Approver filled: New Comments field = G
```

[image]

Can you help?

Comment: You can disregard the code format listed above--those are just the parameters I'd like for the If/Then query

Answer (score 3):

In MS-Access, `switch` is the simpler way to handle multiple conditions:

```
select . . .
       switch([Cardholder] Is Not Null And [Reconciler] Is Not Null And [Approver] Is Not Null, "F",
              [Cardholder] Is Not Null And [Reconciler] Is Not Null, "D",
              [Cardholder] Is Not Null And [Approver] Is Not Null, "E",
              [Reconciler] Is Not Null And [Approver] Is Not Null, "G",
              [Cardholder] Is Not Null, "A",
              [Reconciler] Is Not Null, "B",
              [Approver] Is Not Null, "C",
              1=1, "H"
             )
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have three fields, and each may be either `Null` or `Not Null` there are 2<sup>3</sup> = 8 possible cases.

The following will account for each:

```
NewComments: 
IIf([Cardholder] Is Not Null And [Reconciler] Is Not Null And [Approver] Is Not Null,"F",
    IIf([Cardholder] Is Not Null And [Reconciler] Is Not Null,"D",
        IIf([Cardholder] Is Not Null And [Approver] Is Not Null,"E",
            IIf([Reconciler] Is Not Null And [Approver] Is Not Null,"G",
                IIf([Cardholder] Is Not Null,"A",
                    IIf([Reconciler] Is Not Null,"B",
                        IIf([Approver] Is Not Null,"C",
                            "H"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The final result `"H"` corresponds to the case in which all three fields are `Null`.

The logic could obviously be reversed to remove the `Not` from each statement, but I've constructed the statement based on the example you provided.